# kernel panic occurs in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel

I have Dell INSPIRON N4050. After installing Ubuntu in my laptop and upgrading to 14.04 this kernel panic occur. It happens after every 15 or 30 minutes and my laptop reboots in 30 seconds. Help me out to fix this error:
[image]

mcelog:

```
CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 2: b200000000000014
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
CPU 0 BANK 2 
STATUS b200000000000014 MCGSTATUS 5
R!P !INEXACT! 60:<00000000c1659b05>
TSC 881356fe45
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
CPU 0 BANK 0 TSC 881356fe45 
TIME 1404919237 Wed Jul  9 16:20:37 2014
STATUS 0 MCGSTATUS 0
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 42
PROCESSOR 0:206a7 TIME 1404919237 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 1b
```

Comment: Could upload logs to paste.ubuntu.com and add their links to the question. `/var/log/dmesg.0` , `/var/log/syslog.1` , `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` and the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`

Comment: I have a similar issue with my Samsung 9. It has been working fine on Ubuntu 13.10 and 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

mcetool indicates that this is a hardware error - it could be anything (overheating, bad RAM, bad CPU, bad thermal paste, blocked fans, bad CPU or RAM sockets, ....)